# Safari for Mac tabs menu bar height problem

Tags: css, macos, safari

I have a problem designing web apps that require 100% screen height using the CSS `height: 100vh` inside Safari for Mac.

Every time I open a new tab, and return to the web app tab, it does no resize to take into account that the browser now has around 24px less space because of the tab bar.

Any ideas to handle this issue?

**Code example:**

*HTML file:*

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Safari Bug</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Safari bug instructions</h1>
        <ol>
            <li>Close all tabs in Safari except this page. (You will see a dark bar at the bottom with buttons)</li>
            <li>Open a new tab.</li>
            <li>Return to the tab. (If the bug appear, you no longer will see the buttons withouth scrolling)</li>
        </ol>
        <p></p>
        <nav class="toolbar">
            <button>Button 1</button>
            <button>Button 2</button>
            <button>Button 3</button>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

*CSS file:*

```
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.app {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.toolbar {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

**Updated:** Added test code. Currently happening on Safari 12.0.3 on Mojave 10.14.3

Comment: Can you please include some relevant code so we can see what is wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Nick, I added some code.

Comment: @EduardoAlvarez Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce the problem using Safari 16.3 on macOS Ventura 13.2.1. It looks like the problem may be fixed. [Here is the page](https://donald.net.au/bugs/safari-100vh.html) I used for testing.

However, I do still see a problem when opening this page in a new tab in an existing window, then dragging the tab out to a new window. In this case, the viewport gets larger, so the buttons no longer sit at the bottom but have extra space underneath.

[image]